# Why do I get C2248 (inaccessible member) with a protected static member?

Tags: c++, inheritance

Let's say I have:

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

std::vector<int> Base::m_intList;

class Base
{
public:
    Base();
protected:
    static std::vector<int> m_intList;
};

class Derived : Base
{
public:
    Derived();
protected:
    bool fWhatever;
};

class MoreDerived : Derived
{
public:
    MoreDerived();
private:
    HRESULT DoStuff();
};

Base::Base()
{

}

Derived::Derived()
{

}

MoreDerived::MoreDerived()
{

}

HRESULT MoreDerived::DoStuff()
{
    for (auto it = m_intList.begin(); it != m_intList.end(); it++)
    {
        std::cout << *it;
    }
}
```

When I try to compile this, I get "m_intList: cannot access inaccessible member declared in class 'MoreDerived'".

**Question**: Why can't I access a protected static member in the derived class's DoStuff function?

Comment: `Derived` inherits from `Base` by `private`. Is it your intent?

Comment: `std::vector<int> Base::m_intList;` is an error because `Base` is not declared.  Please post the exact code that gave you the error you are asking about

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`class Derived : Base` means `class Derived : private Base`. The behaviour of private inheritance is:

- `protected` members of the base class become `private` members of the derived class.
- `private` members of the base class have *no access* as members of the derived class.

So `m_intList` is:

- `protected` in `Base`
- `private` in `Derived`
- *no access* in `MoreDerived`

hence your error.